# Rails: save a model associations in a single transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have troubles with updated_at columns, that does not seems to be equal inside the same transaction:

```
@my_model = FactoryGirl.build(:my_model_bare)
@my_model.first_assoc = FactoryGirl.build(:first_assoc_sample)
@my_model.second_assoc = FactoryGirl.build(:second_assoc_sample)
@my_model.save!
puts @my_model.first_assoc.updated_at.iso8601(3)
puts @my_model.second_assoc.updated_at.iso8601(3)
```

At the end, `first_assoc.updated_at != second_assoc.updated_at` even if both models have been saved inside the same transaction !?

How can I force updated_at to be the same for all operation inside a transaction ? Is it a mysql problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The 'created_at' and 'updated_at' columns are populated by Rails.

As you are using FactoryGirl I'm assuming you need this for testing purposes.  Based on that take a look at the TimeCop gem:

https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Timecop gives the ability to freeze time.

If you really need to set the created_at and updated_at times manually you can just assign them values:

```
current_time = Time.now

@my_model.created_at = current_time
@my_model.updated_at = current_time
```

You would need to manually set the values for any related objects too

Comment: Thanks, but it's only a test that highlights a problem that arise in my normal workflow :( But i will use timecop in tests !

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord sets `updated_at` in datetime with ms. So they will not be equal.
For see it you can use:

```
Rails.logger.info @model.updated_at.to_i
```

You always can update `update_at` manually.

Comment: it seems that rails put it's own datetime inside this column, instead of using "NOW()", which should update with same value transaction wide. You know if there is a way to change that ?

Comment: Nope.
Only MySql 5.6 supports fractional seconds in datetime.
In your updated_at field activerecord stores, for example: 2013-04-30 11:34:58.62718 but mysql allow save to db only '2013-04-30 11:34:58'.

Comment: No, my question was: is it possible to replace rails 'Time.zone.now' by mysql 'NOW()' in my updated_at column ?